# How safe are Google's suggested passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-protection, hashing

When I create a new account on any site, Google suggests a password under the option "Use suggested password". These passwords seem pretty strong but are hard to remember for a human.

It also says something along the lines of "Google will save this password, so you won't have to remember it."

Could I be certain I won't get locked out of my account? Where are these passwords stored, and how safe are they?

Comment: "Where are these passwords stored, and how safe are they?" - They are managed by Chrome, the same mechanism, that Chrome has always used.  If something happens to your profile then your passwords are gone.   You can avoid that heartache by synchronizing your profile.

Comment: @Ramhound So I need to keep using Chrome to avail the password, or I may lose an account? Is the password stored locally or in a cloud storage?

Comment: @niamulbengali - Google has documented how their password safe mechanism works.  The alternative is to use a password manager that supports multiple browsers and environments